# Does time get considered in deciding Duplicate Questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

A while back HWE for 14.04 was released and people had a bit of trouble upgrading to the new update.  Which is fine and all.  However, I came on site today to see [this question flagged as dup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588558/unable-to-upgrade-trusty-14-04-1-to-the-14-04-2-hwe/588606#588606) to [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588695/cant-install-libglew-dev-because-libcheese-and-libclutter-dont-have-the-requir)
I understand the first one is nowhere near appropriate seeing as how this question isn't a "how do I upgrade" but a "why isn't it upgrading" question. 
Some input on the matter would be nice.

Comment: It depends on the flagger. There's no official requirement that the original be older than the duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

There are no hard rules on which direction close-dupes and merges should go. Quality should be at least as important as time when choosing a master question.

If there is a lot of time between the questions, it may also be worth considering that they are different issues and closing the new one may not be appropriate.

---

In this case, there's a difference in quality:

- The master is researched and updated, while the dupe is just an error dump.
- The answers (not yours) on the dupe are fairly low quality (all -1), while each of the master's seems to add something.
- The master's answers also link out to the actual problem on Launchpad.

Objectively, the activity on the master question (despite it being hours newer) is better. I think that's why it's been closed the way it has.